# Jquery : required dependency not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

event amount only required when is_paid dropdown select 'Yes'.
and amount should be more than 0.

here is code

```
 event_amount: {

                    required: {
                        depends: function () {
                            var dropdown_val = $("#is_paid").val();
                            if(dropdown_val == 1) {
                                var amount = $('#event_amount').val();

                                if(parseInt(amount) > 0){
alert('if');
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert('else');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and when I tried to submit form it will alert 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the amount is greater than 0 in a separate rule, not as part of the `depends` property for the `required` rule.

```
event_amount: {
    required: {
        depends: function() {
            return $("#is_paid").val() == '1';
        }
    },
    min: 1
}
```